# How to calculate $\sigma^{-1} (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma(x_i))$ in a numerically stable way?

Tags: logistic, ensemble-learning

Suppose I have $n$ logits $x_1, \dots, x_n$, where $n$ is not too large. They are real numbers in $(-\infty, +\infty)$ and correspond to probabilities in $(0, 1)$ via the formula $p_i = \sigma(x_i)$, where $\sigma$ is the sigmoid function. I want to calculate the logit $\hat x = \sigma^{-1} (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n p_i) = \sigma^{-1} (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma(x_i))$ in a numerically stable way. How do I do this? Ideally, I want a code snippet for pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose that $\sigma$ is just the sigmoidal, which Pytorch has for sure an implementation, so you just need to find the inverse of the sigmoidal:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right)^{-1} = \log\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)
$$

Then you can do whatever you want with this to make it more stable, for example:
$$
\log\left(\epsilon_1 + \frac{x}{\epsilon_2 + 1-x}\right)
$$
to avoid division by zero or the log of zero

Comment: Actually, both sigmoid and logit functions have an implementation in Pytorch. However, the whole construction won't behave well when $x$ is large, so I was hoping for either a tricky way using `logsumexp` or a tricky way similar to a good implementation of `logsumexp`.

Comment: Actually, the PyTorch implementation includes a parameter `eps` that will prevent it from blowing up near 0 or 1. If this isn't what you want, can you [edit] your question to explain what problem you're trying to solve and how this computation fits into solving it?

Comment: @CrabMan following what  Sycorax said, in case the epsilon parameter does not solves your problem, please can you give more info in what you want to do, because is intrinsic of the sigmoidal^-1 to be very sensitive to numbers between 0 and 1, and IEEE754 does not help you